# Can I put a Flip Light in the boot of my car?

Tags: car, hyundai, trunk

I have an Hyundai i30 and the light in the boot is very dim , I recently bought somthing similar to  [flip light](https://www.bunnings.com.au/dats-led-flip-switch_p0013960)

I wondering if it is ok to stick it on the walls of the boot.

**I'm mainly concerned if any heat would effect it and may cause it to explode or something.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ought to be fine to add additional, LED, battery powered lights to the boot.  The temperatures in there will be roughly similar to that in the cabin.  Be sure the secure it sufficiently otherwise it may fall into your luggage.

As an alternative, you could replace the bulb in the existing light fitting in the boot with an SMD LED bulb.  These are incredibly bright but produce little heat and draw little current, certainly less than the incandescent bulb that's in there.  This gives you the advantage of not worrying about the battery in a self-contained light going flat.

Comment: thanks , regarding the SMD LED bulb , is that something I can do without going to the service center ?

Comment: Changing the boot bulb ought to be a fairly simple operation.  Check your cars handbook if it came with one to see if it's detailed in there.